# C++ Qt unable to parse JSON array correctly

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt-creator

I am trying to parse json with Qt but I have no success. This is the ouput that I get from the server:

```
[{"anni":2019},{"anni":2018},{"anni":2017}]
```

Where that's generated from this simple php:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

The `$data` is an array containing the values you see above. I am using this piece of code in Qt 5.11.2:

```
void MainWindow::showYears() {   

    //reply is a QNetworkReply* reply;
    if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        //some error managment
    } else {

        auto responsedata = reply->readAll();

        QJsonArray years = QJsonDocument::fromJson(responsedata).array();          
        qDebug() << QString{responsedata};

        for(const QJsonValue& y : years) {
            QJsonObject obj = y.toObject();

            //doing "qDebug() << r" shows that r is "" (empty!)
            auto r = obj["anni"].toString();

            ui->comboBoxP->addItem(r);
        }

    }

}
```

What's wrong here?

---

Please note that `qDebug() << QString{responsedata};` prints `"[{\"anni\":2019},{\"anni\":2018},{\"anni\":2017}]"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value for your field `anni` is an integer. Using the member function `toString` will not convert it to a string representation. it will return NULL. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html#toString

Try with: `auto r = QString::number(obj["anni"].toInt());`

Comment: Thank you! I misunderstood the usage of toString(), I thought it was able to convert the field to a string.